# Why D3DCompile doesn't support unicode sources?

Tags: windows, directx

If i pass a buffer with unicode source (wchar_t*) into `D3DCompile`, i'll get a "unrecognize character" error.

Why it doesn't support unicode source? doesn't all Windows API and COM support unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Win32 APIs that accept text as input support both `char*` and `wchar_t*`.  `D3DCompile` is an exception, and only accepts `char*`.  As long as you avoid using unicode characters outside of comments, you should be able to use the [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) function to convert the text to a form that can be used with `D3DCompile`.